# Help find hard integrals that evaluate to $59$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

My father and I, on birthday cards, give mathematical equations for each others new age.  This year, my father will be turning $59$.

I want to try and make a definite integral that equals $59$.  So far I can only think of ones that are easy to evaluate. I was wondering if anyone had a definite integral (preferably with no elementary antiderivative) that is difficult to evaluate and equals $59$?  Make it as hard as possible, feel free to add whatever you want to it!

Comment: Now let's just hope that your father doesn't read math.stackexchange.com...

Comment: Wiki-hammered as this is a bit list with a subjective (as hard as possible) answer.

Comment: Yeah... or your dad might know right away that the solution evaluates to 59... on his birthday... when he just turned 59.

Comment: The fun is on proving it. So, it doesn't matter if the father sees this post or if he/she knows the answer is 59.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You might try the following:
$$ \frac{64}{\pi^3} \int_0^\infty \frac{ (\ln x)^2 (15-2x)}{(x^4+1)(x^2+1)}\ dx $$

Comment: Is that $$\ln(x^2)$$ or $$(\ln x)^2$$ ?

Comment: @ypercube: the second one.

Comment: Added to the card.  Thanks very much!

Comment: How does one start to solve this?

Comment: Does the indefinite integral of the integrand give a closed-form solution?

Comment: Using the Risch-Norman algorithm, the antiderivative is not elementary.  Maple doesn't find a closed-form antiderivative.

Answer (score 140):

compact : $$\int_0^\infty \frac{(x^4-2)x^2}{\cosh(x\frac{\pi}2)}\,dx$$

Comment: With added benefit of having very few arbitrary-looking constants.

Comment: @Alex: should be even better in 2 years! :-)

Comment: I like this Easy to read, no crazy exponents yet nontrivial solution.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha timed out trying to evaluate it.

Comment: @Joe: hint for fast evaluation : use the generating function for [Euler numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number).

Comment: @Raymond 59 = 61 - 2?

Comment: @Joe: yes easy isn't it? :-) (and that's why it will be simpler in 2014!)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni There should be a lemma I am missing, but why $\int t^{2n}/cosh(t \pi/2) = |E_{2n}|$ ?

Comment: A derivation without using the generating function :
\begin{align}
\frac {I(m)}2:=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^m}{2\,\cosh(t)}dt&=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^m\;e^{-t}}{1+e^{-2t}}dt\\
&=\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\;t^m\;e^{-(2k+1)t}\;dt\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac {(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^m}\int_0^\infty u^m\;e^{-u}\frac{du}{2k+1}\;\\
&=\Gamma(m+1)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac {(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^{m+1}}\\
&=\Gamma(m+1)\,\beta(m+1)\\
\end{align}
And the properties of the [Dirichlet Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) applied to $m=2n\,$ give :

Comment: $$I(2n)=(2n)!\;\beta(2n+1)=(-1)^n\;E_{2n}\;\left(\frac {\pi}2\right)^{2n+1}$$
while the indefinite integral returned by Alpha for $n=3$ looks like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28x%5E6/cosh%28x%29,x%29).

Comment: @user10676: There is indeed a lemma : $$\int_0^\infty \frac {\cosh(a\,x)}{\cosh(b\,x)}\;dx=\frac {\pi}{2b}\sec\left(\frac{\pi\,a}{2\,b}\right)$$
that we will use written as (with $b:=\pi/2$) :
$$\frac 1{\cosh(t)}=\int_0^\infty \frac {\cos(t\,x)}{\cosh(\pi\,x/2)}\;dx$$

These formulas may be proved with [this method](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171073/how-to-evaluate-these-integrals-by-hand/171088#171088). 

This implies : $$\left(\frac d{dt}\right)^{2n}\frac 1{\cosh(t)}=(-1)^n\int_0^\infty \frac {x^{2n}\cos(t\,x)}{\cosh(\pi\,x/2)}\;dx$$
Conclude with the limit $\lim_{t\to 0}$.

Comment: since the [Euler numbers generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number) :
$$\frac 1{\cosh(t)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty E_n\frac {t^n}{n!}$$
allows to rewrite the left part simply as $E_{2n}$.

Answer (score 43):

Combining an very difficult [infinite sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan#Mathematical_achievements) with the indefinite integral of $\sin(x)/x$ over $\mathbb R$, which has no elementary antiderivative, gives

$$\frac{118\sqrt{2}}{9801}\int_{\mathbb R} \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(4k)!(1103+26390k)}{(k!)^4396^{4k}}\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\right)dx=59\cdot \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot \pi=59$$

which should be tough enough to stump anyone who hasn't seen them before.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the downvote?

Comment: @JoachimSauer: It's probably due to my dumbness, but I don't see where the 59 is hidden in 108? 59*2=118, if you meant that?

Comment: @JoachimSauer That was actually a typo on my part. $108$ was meant to be $118$.

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع It's only a conjecture?

Comment: @MichaelT After some research I found that it isn't.

Answer (score 24):

There's also

$$\int_0^\infty \! x^3 e^{-(118)^{-1/2}x^2} \, dx$$

Comment: The 118 is a bit too obvious, assuming it's not just coincidence that 118/2 = 59

Comment: @Random832 True, but I figured I'd write down an integral that gives his father a reasonable chance of figuring it out...  ...at least I myself would struggle with some of the other alternatives.

Comment: Yeah! Our objective is not to teach him mathematics for that instance rather to provide him with the pleasure, challenge and thrill of solving such integral!!! Isn't it....

Answer (score 24):

Somewhat complicated, but...

$$\begin{align*}\frac{12}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{\frac12\cos\,t}}{5-4\cos\,t}&\left(2\cos \left(t-\frac{\sin\,t}{2}\right)+3\cos\left(2t-\frac{\sin\,t}{2}\right)+\right.\\&\left.14\cos\left(3t-\frac{\sin\,t}{2}\right)-8\cos\left(4t-\frac{\sin\,t}{2}\right)\right)\mathrm dt=59\end{align*}$$

As a hint on how I obtained this integral, I used Cauchy's differentiation formula on a certain function (I'll edit this answer later to reveal that function), and took the real part...

Comment: Waiting on your edit as promised.... `:-)`

Comment: Ah, shoot; let me look for my notes on this... if memory serves, I trolled through OEIS and looked for generating functions.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8PfsQ.png

Comment: Almost 8 years later. You still haven't posted the solution. Please...

Comment: Still waiting for that solution.

Comment: Still waiting for the solution! :D