# Is there a formula for $k\pi ^n$, if $n$ is an odd number and $k$ is a rational number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

I always find the formula for $k\pi ^n$ when $n$ is an even number and $k$ is a rational number, but I did't find for an odd number.

Comment: What do you mean by a "formula" if $k\pi^n$ is not itself what you seek?

Comment: Maybe showing us your formula for the even case will shed some light?

Comment: For example, there is this formula $\frac{\pi ^2}{6}=1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}.......$

Comment: $\pi^2=\pi^2+0+0+0+\cdots$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Dirichlet beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletBetaFunction.html) may satisfy you :
$$\beta(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^x}$$
with the table of values :
\begin{array} {c|c}
n&\beta(n)\\
\hline
1&\frac {\pi}4\\
2&K\\
3&\frac {\pi^3}{32}\\
4&\beta(4)\\
5&\frac {5\,\pi^5}{1536}\\
\end{array}
with $K$ the [Catalan constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html).

Here the $n$ even cases are the difficult ones as opposed to the $\zeta$ odd cases !

A parallel with $\zeta$ is proposed in this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510363/a-series-related-to-zeta-3) (Euler numbers replacing Bernoulli numbers...).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the formula for $n$ even you are talking about comes from the [riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers). In the same articles you can read that a general formula for $\zeta(2k+1)$ is still an open problem.

Comment: I mean any formula not necessary compatible with zeta reimann function.