# Prove that the set of accumulation points is circle. Find it center and radius

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following sequence $a_n= \prod_{k=1}^n (1+\frac{i}{k})$
I need to prove that the set of accumulation points is circle. Also I need to find it center and radius. I don’t know how to attempt, could someone give any hints ? So first I was trying to understand what is the center and radius of circle. Also I think , that I need to somehow rewrite $a_n$’s

Comment: To get an idea for what all this might mean, and some hints on what the answer might be it might help to experiment in something like Mathematica first, e.g. `p[n_] := Product[1 + I/k, {k, 1, n}]; ListPlot[
 Table[{Re[p[n]], Im[p[n]]}, {n, 1, 100}]]` (maybe you can get WolframAlpha to plot something similar)

Comment: So can I put it in wolfram alpha? Because I don’t have Mathematica

Comment: @Pixel I think that'll be too slow since the harmonic series is involved in the product, which is terribly slow to **diverge**. See my answer.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel it's not bad tbh... for $n=1..700$ it quickly shows the formation of a circle, which looks centred at the origin and with finite radius, around $1.9$, so I still think it's useful if you're feeling a bit lost and gives food for thought. The next thing would be to examine the real and imaginary parts as in the answers.

Comment: @BeesaFangirlDOTO check out a trial version or better still use a free one like Sage.

Answer (score 1):

We consider the argument and magnitude of the product separately.

The argument of $a_n$ is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\tan^{-1}\frac1k>\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$
which is the harmonic series, diverging to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus the $a_n$ circle around the origin forever.

The magnitude of $a_n$ is
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\sqrt{1+\frac1{k^2}}$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\sqrt{1+\frac1{k^2}}=\sqrt{\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac1{k^2}\right)}=\sqrt{\frac{\sinh\pi}\pi}$$
(see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786046/infinite-product-prod-limits-k-1-infty-left1-fracx2k2-pi2-right) for the derivation of the last step). Thus the accumulation points of $(a_n)$ form a circle centred at the origin with radius $\sqrt{\frac{\sinh\pi}\pi}=1.9173100\dots$

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite $1+\frac{1}{k}$ as $\frac{\sqrt{k^2+1}}{k} e^{i \arctan(1/k)}$. From this, you find
\begin{align*}
a_n = \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n \sqrt{(k^2+1)}}{n!} e^{i \sum_{k=1}^n \arctan(1/k)}
\end{align*}
Now, since $\sum_{k=1}^n \arctan(1/k)$ diverges ($\arctan(x) = \mathcal{O}(x)$ for $x \to 0$), it suffices to show that $\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n \sqrt{(k^2+1)}}{n!}$ converges. Now, $\sqrt{k^2+1} \leq k + \frac{1}{2k}$, and hence, we get $\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n \sqrt{(k^2+1)}}{n!} \leq \prod_{k=1}^n (1 + \frac{1}{2k^2})$, which converges.

Comment: And then... find the exact radius of the circle?

Comment: The question was only to prove they lie on a circle. Apparently you can use Euler's sine expansion to find the radius, but that's not the question.
(see @ParclyTaxel 's answer)

Comment: Did you read the second part of the title?

Comment: Haha, nope. sorry