# Evaluate $ \int_0^\infty \cos(x)/\cosh(x) dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to evaluate
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{\cosh(x)} dx $$ 
through Residue Theory, but it has an infinite number of poles in x=(2n+1)pi/2, I couldn't find the way to the solution that is $$\frac{\pi\ }{2 \cosh \ (\pi\ /2)}.$$

I tried also the Method of the Fourier Integral, but couldn't find the answer too. I'm in this question for over 1.5h and  have a test tomorrow, can someone help me?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171073/how-to-evaluate-these-integrals-by-hand

Comment: Thanks man, I wasn't abble to find a question like this. Thank you

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091007162254AAZXzt5