# Find my error in evaluation of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{e^x+e^{-x}}$?

Tags: definite-integrals

I was trying to evaluate $$I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{e^x+e^{-x}}\text{d}x,$$ and am trying to find my error. Here's my work, with tons of algebra left out.

$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{e^x+e^{-x}}\text{d}x$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}\left(e^{(1+i)x}+e^{(1-i)x}\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n}\text{d}x$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\int_0^{\infty}x^{2n} e^{(1+i)x}\text{d}x+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\int_0^{\infty}x^{2n} e^{(1-i)x}\text{d}x$$

On those two integrals I do $u=-(1+i)x$ and $u=-(1-i)x$, respectively:

$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{-1}{(1+i)^{2n+1}}\int_0^{\infty}u^{2n} e^{-u}\text{d}u+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{-1}{(1-i)^{2n+1}\int_0^{\infty}u^{2n} e^{-u}}\text{d}u$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{-1}{(1+i)^{2n+1}}\Gamma(2n)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{-1}{(1-i)^{2n+1}}\Gamma(2n)$$

At this point I know I've screwed up, because these sums don't diverge. But I'll show my last steps:

$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)!\frac{1}{(1+i)^{2n+1}+\frac{1}{(1-i)^{2n+1}}}.$$

Omitting some complex numbers work:

$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)!\frac{-\sqrt{2}\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}(2n+1))}{2^n}$$

And this certainly diverges because $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n-1)!}{2^n}=\infty$...

Someone help!

Comment: What a silly error. And they're divergent anyways. I know that this can be evaluated other ways, but can I salvage this line of reasoning?

Comment: It is not only one line which would need "salvation". $\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{e^x+e^{-x}}=\left(e^{(1+i)x}+e^{(1-i)x}\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^ne^{2nx}\ne\left(e^{(1+i)x}+e^{(1-i)x}\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n},$ and both are anyway divergent for $x>1.$ And $\int_0^{\infty}x^{2n} e^{(1\pm i)x}\text{d}x$ are divergent. And when $x$ belongs to $(0,+\infty),$ $u=-(1+i)x$ and $u=-(1-i)x$ don't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the value of $\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\cos x}{e^x+e^{-x}} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268181/find-the-value-of-int-infty-infty-frac-cos-xexe-x-dx)

Comment: Hint: $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\cos (x)}{\exp (-x)+\exp (x)} \, dx=\frac{1}{4} \pi  \text{sech}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$