# Prove $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{\cosh(x)}dx=\frac{\pi}{2\cosh(\pi/2)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I came across this challenging integral:

> Prove
> $$I:=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{\cosh(x)}dx=\frac{\pi}{2\cosh(\pi/2)}$$

**My attempt**

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{\cosh(x)}dx=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cosh(x)}\Bigg]_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)\sinh(x)}{\cosh^2(x)}$$
I don't think this is the right way. Do I need to take the real part of $e^{ix}$? How do I solve this integral?

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate these integrals by hand](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171073/how-to-evaluate-these-integrals-by-hand), [Solve $\int \limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{\cosh(x)} dx$ without complex integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1275759/695196)